# FOSUserBundle routes not resloving - redirected to default controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Everytime I try to access `mypage/register`, or any of the other pages FOSUserBudnle created, I get redirected to my default controller `mypage/` instead of the registration page.

These are my routing files:

```
(app\config\routing.yml)

my_website:
resource: "@MyWebsiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/profile
```

And the other one (Resources\config\routing.yml)

```
mywebsite_first:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: MyWebsiteBundle:Default:index }

mywebsite_calendar:
    pattern: /{_locale}/calendar
    defaults: { _controller: MyWebsiteBundle:Calendar:index }

mywebsite_home:
    pattern: /{_locale}/home
    defaults: { _controller: MyWebsiteBundle:Home:index }

mywebsite_messages:
    pattern: /{_locale}/messages
    defaults: { _controller: MyWebsiteBundle:Messages:index }
```

Also - my security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using `{_locale}` in route, you should also provide requirements (see @Rpg600's answer) and defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because it match with _locale parameter of your website's route, the Symfony router will always choose the first matching route it finds.

You need to add a route requirements :

```
mywebsite_first:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: MyWebsiteBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
    _locale: en|fr|de
```

or simply place website's route after FOSUser's route.